# Simple pointer question (Sharing a vector between different classes)

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory, pointers, vector

I have a class AudioDeviceManager that passes a std::vector by reference to an AudioAnalyzer class.

I want other objects to be able to access this vector (that is passed to the AudioAnalyzer class). To do this, I created a pointer in the AudioAnalyzer class:

```
std::vector<float> *pointer;
```

I created a getter for it using Objective-C properties. 
When I am in the same class, I can seem to access it fine and pass it to other objects (by reference)

```
NSLog(@"%i", [self pointer]);
det->process(time, *[self pointer]);
```

However, I can't seem to access it from another class, spectrum
I initialize this spectrum class with the method call (fft_data is also a pointer to a std::vector)

```
- (id) initWithDataVec:(std::vector<float>*)address {
...
fft_data = address;
...
```

But `NSLog(@"value: %i", fft_data);` returns 0.

Writing `NSLog(@"value: %i", &fft_data) returns what appears to be a valid address. But isn't this the address of the pointer?

I am not sure if my code is correct. I am looking for a way to "share" a single vector among different classes. Ideally, one class will receive a pointer to the vector that they can access at any time, without having to have a function called by another class.

Comment: How do you call initWithDataVec with std::vector<float> pointer? And I recommend you to use "%p" instead of "%i" for pointer in NSLog format.

Comment: std::vector<float> *toData = [analyzer pointer];
 spectrum = [[Spectrum alloc] initWithDataVec:toData];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just pass (by reference) the same instance of the same std::vector to the constructors of all classes that need it?

Comment: Wouldn't that make my design tightly coupled? I have a "Spectrum" class that draws a spectrum display of currently playing audio...AudioAnalyzer would have to know about this class to pass its vector to its constructor.

Comment: Yes, the nicer way to do this is to have a separate builder class/function that sets up all objects, and passes the correct objects to the dependent object's constructors. This way all classes get what they need without having to know each other's inner details. You can also use this to pass in mock/test versions of objects in test code to facilitate unit testing. This technique is called Dependency Injection, try Googling for that.